# How can I download the Unreal 4 mannequin into Blender with materials?

Tags: modeling, import, unreal-engine

I found this model over here https://www.renderhub.com/rip-van-winkle/mannequin-from-unreal-engine-4
But the model is imported without its materials.
How can I import it into Blender with its proper materials so it looks as it does in UE4?